# Memory (handle) leak in jsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

The latest jsonServiceClient (4.0.54) is leaving handles open after every synchronous GET request (and possibly POSTS).

My guess is that it's something like the stream for the body, if unread, remains held open and slowly grinds our tests to a halt. We didn't follow it up further after wasting a full day assuming it was our own code :/

Running a loop of 10,000 fetches slows our tests down significantly, despite disposing of the client.

This doesn't happen with the Async get.

Comment: This isn't actually a question. This is a bug report. I suggest either posting here https://forums.servicestack.net/ or contacting support@servicestack.net

Comment: The Service Clients does [dispose of the of the RequestStream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8f527da7a669a60cca14e9b4bccd5a4da634ed62/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceClientBase.cs#L755) after every request, if you have a repro please submit it to [ServiceStack Issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues).

Comment: Note: If your [clients are accessing Raw Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#accessing-client-raw-responses) you'll need to dispose of the `Stream` or `HttpWebResponse` at the call-site once you've finished using it.

Comment: Thanks for the info on where to go. There's very little on the ServiceStack site to suggest where bugs are reported, mainly a suggestion to go here!

Comment: @JSobell I've provided the link to [ServiceStack Issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues) in my previous comment. You can find the support links in your [Account's Support Page](https://servicestack.net/account/support).

Answer (score 3):

This issue was identified in this [ServiceStack Customer Forums thread](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/handle-leak-in-jsonserviceclient/2124/4) as not having disposed of `HttpWebResponse` responses. This issue can be resolved by calling it within `using{}` statement, e.g:

```
using (HttpWebResponse webRes = client.Get(requestUri)) {
    byte[] bytes webRes.GetResponseStream().ReadFully();
    string str = bytes.FromUtf8Bytes();
}
```